# How to install PHP 5.3 - mhash in Centos?

Tags: php, hash, centos, rpm

How to install php 5.3 mhash in my centos. Where to get that RPM files. Every where it is showing up to 5.2 version only. Please help me. How can I install that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instann the 5.3 from here http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/SRPMS/ but the mhash is off:

From 5.3.0 Release Notes:

The mhash extension is no more provided. See the alternative extension HASH Message Digest Framework -> https://www.php.net/hash